# Unable to open apps in my lumia

Tags: lumia-520

in my windows phone suddenly i could not open half of the apps.
in applist some of the apps are listed as @{Microsoft.MS(app name)
eg @{Microsoft.MSBattery, i cant open these apps also. please help me as i cant open any messaging app as well as media apps

Comment: What version are you running? Had a similar issue with the Windows 10 desktop preview.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I had trouble in logging in, then  I completely forgot about it. I did hard reset and downloaded all the apps that I have previously installed. Now everything works fine

Comment: One regret is I could not get some of my private information that was stored in some of the apps which I was unable to access it. For example like WhatsApp chat and some personal diary app.