# Unable to open whatsapp in lumia 520

Tags: whatsapp

I updated whatsapp on my Lumia 520 today and after that I am unable to open whatsapp. Whenever I try to open it, the screen just goes back to the home. I tried restarting my phone and also reinstalling whatsapp but nothing works. Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9841/106

Comment: Have you tried doing a soft reset? If not you should consider trying a hard reset.